# What happens when os.system() is executed in python thread?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, system-calls

I am new to python threading. I am trying to understand what happens when os.system() is called from a python thread. I understand that threads do share file descriptors, heap, code and global variables. I also read that os.system(cmd) creates a new subshell and there it executes the cmd provided.

My question is, when python threads call os.system(cmd) and the cmd executes "./test.exe input_file.dat", does the process for ./test.exe share anything (i.e. input files, address space, heap, etc.) with the python threads? In other words, does os.system(cmd) create a new process which has no relation with the caller process or thread?

Below, I provided the python code I wrote.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import os

semaphore = threading.Semaphore(3)

def run_command(cmd):
    with semaphore:
        os.system(cmd)

for i in range(3):
    threading.Thread(target=run_command, args=("./test.exe input_file.dat", )).start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when os.system() is executed in python thread?

- A thread is created. This thread -- like all threads -- shares its address space with the thread that created it.
- That thread calls `fork()` to create a new child process almost exactly like itself. Only the thread that called `fork()` is present in the child process; other threads are not copied. The child process has a separate address space from the parent process, but has memory mapped at all the same addresses.

  (This child process is only present for a very brief time -- you won't see it in this state unless you take specific steps in a debugger to pause the process here. [Using threads in conjunction with `fork()` is generally inadvisable](https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them), but in this case it's mostly okay.)
- The new child process calls `execve()` to fully replace itself with a new process running `test.exe`. The address space of the child process is destroyed, and a new one created for the image of the new process.
- Meanwhile, the thread that called `fork()` now calls `waitpid()` (or possibly `wait()`) to suspend its execution until the new process finishes. Once that happens, `os.system()` returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot duskwuff for your detailed explanation. The line "The child process has a separate address space from the parent process, but has memory mapped at all the same addresses" really excites me. I will dig more about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When we execute os.system(cmd) from a Python thread T1, the new subshell is created as a subprocess of T1. Therefore, test.exe shares T1's address space (which is basically the address space of the T1's parent, Python code). Using pmap on Linux, my answer can be verified.

[Here I provide the pmap output for the parent process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPaah.jpg)

[Here I provide the pmap output for the subprocess (test.exe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEyCW.jpg)

Comment: Subprocesses do **not** share address space with their parent process. That's precisely what distinguishes a thread from a process!

Comment: Hi duskwuff, as I am new to python threading, need your assistance to understand what is wrong with my answer. When I execute the python code provided above and use Linux's pmap command, it shows that the parent process ( the Python code ) and the subprocesses for ./test.exe are mapped on the same address space. So, can you please tell me whether I am making any mistake with the pmap command output?

Comment: The fact that two processes have memory mapped at the same address does not mean that they "share address space". Try comparing another unrelated process; you'll probably find that _everything_ uses those addresses by default.